# Search within a category page on a MediaWiki site

Tags: search, mediawiki

I'm trying to search for text on a category page of a MediaWiki website. But the search seems to only work on article pages. How can I also search on category (or all) pages on a MediaWiki website?

This question is similar to this one: [Search within a category on a MediaWiki site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28412/280816)

Therefore, I want to emphasize, that I am not asking about the search on article pages of a certain category, but about the search on category pages themselves, as the may contain text as well, allongside the listing of subcategories and articles.

Comment: Searching works fine on category pages. For a more useful answer, you'll need to share more details about what exactly you tried.

Comment: @Tgr Thx for your pointer. I then managed to find it out by myself and added it as an [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158793/280816) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MediaWiki search performs its search *only* on article pages by default. To extend the search, you have to add more namespaces to the search.

Depending on your MediaWiki version, you can add additional namespaces (e. g. "Category") by one of the following methods:

- In older versions (e. g. 1.27.1), in your search results, click on the "Advanced" tab and select your desired additional namespaces.
- In the *current* version (1.37.0), in your search results, under "Search in", click on "Add namespaces" and select your desired additional namespaces:[image]

Or you can prepend the namespace to your search query (e. g. for "Category")<sup>1</sup>:

```
Category:MySearchQuery
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Contributed by [Tgr](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/5293/) through the comments.

Comment: You can also just prefix the search query with `Category:`, I think.

Comment: @Tgr This seems to work, too!